# How to make such animations in Wordpress or Wix?

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, velo

I am new in Wordpress recently I got a project. The project is to make a website like this https://www.jamil.com.au/. When you open the site on the very top you can see some animations. Now the problem is that is there any specific plugin for this or its custom code. Your help will be highly appreciated...
Thanks in Advance.

I have tried nothing yet Becuase I don't have any idea about such animations.

Comment: You can easily achieve that with move.js: https://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too vague and does not show any evidence of you having researched the problem. Please edit your post to make the question clearer to those that wish to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think there are plugins to do this kind of very specific animations, if you feel comfortable with css, you can try to do it with the help of "keyframes" and "transform" properties.

You will be able to move your elements with different delays.